# Manipulate control properties inside panel

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a desktop application using C#.Net and win forms, i want to make a series of text boxes Read-Only in form load, code below doesnt work on formloa , but it applies on all text boxes in the form.

```
        foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        { 
            if(ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textbx = ctrl as TextBox; 
                if(textbx.ReadOnly == false)
                {
                    textbx.ReadOnly = true; 
                }
            }
        }
```

but i want to manipulate those Textboxes that are inside in my Form1 container. how can i do that ?
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through every control in Form1 so of course you get all the textboxes in your loop.

If you put your textboxes inside a container like a groupbox then you can use the groupbox in your foreach instead of the entire Form1 object.

So you'd have a groupbox control on your form and inside that you'd have the textboxes that you want to set to ReadOnly.

```
foreach(Control ctrl in myTextBoxContainer.Controls)
        { 
            if(ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textbx = ctrl as TextBox; 
                if(textbx.ReadOnly == false)
                {
                    textbx.ReadOnly = true; 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, how can i learn all of this material , can u suggest a source?

Comment: I'd look for a course or a good book that deals with winforms and basic to intermediate C#.

I can recommend this one as it really helped me recently:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027812.do